# Testing ServiceProviders in a standalone package?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5, codeception

I'm weighing the pro's and con's of testing my ServiceProviders in a standalone package.

Since the laravel application is not a dependency of the package, I don't think I should/can write integration tests.

But there are times where I make typos in the use statements that causes me to create a whole new version just for these small errors. Do you unit test your ServiceProvider bindings for additional code coverage?

Mocking closures just looks like a pain and it's looking more like expensive spell checking than actual testing.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote [a package](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant) that closely integrates with L 5.1 LTS. In order to test all functionalities and not depend on Mocks (mainly because it also writes webserver files too, which are a pain in the ...) I did include the whole framework to test integration too.

As a result in [one of my unit tests](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/blob/master/tests/TenancySetupTest.php#L17) I even test whether the ServiceProviders have been properly loaded and are available before continuing any further tests.

Even though the best practice is to make framework-agnostic packages, sometimes it might be nice to know the package actually keeps working on the frameworks you find important.

Comment: That makes more sense to me. I think programming agnositically is a virtue but the very fact I'm making a ServiceProvider which is a Laravel specific implementation I should just accept the fact it's a Laravel implementation. Makes sense.